# How to set the tree store and tree node is not closing/collapsing back

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I am using a treepanel for my extJS application.

Here is my code:

```
{
    xtype: 'treepanel',
    useArrows: true,
    autoScroll: false,
    animate: true,
    animateShadow: true,
    enableDD: false,
    id: 'myTreePanel',
    rootVisible: false,
    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        root: {
            expanded: true,
            children: [],
        }
    }),
}
```

Now after one ajax call on click of some button I am getting the response. I am pasting the sample values of what kind of response I am getting. Now in the function this is how I am seeting the store.

```
myTreeData = [{
        children: [],
        text: 'text1'
    },
    {
        children: [],
        text: 'text2'
    },
    {
        children: [{
            children: null,
            text: 'text31'
        }, {
            children: null,
            text: 'text32'
        }],
        text: 'text3'
    },
    {
        children: [],
        text: 'text4'
    },
    {
        children: [],
        text: 'text5'
    }
]


myFunction: function(me.response) {
    var myTreeData = response.myTreeData;
    for (var i = 0; i < myTreeData.length; i++) {
        myTreeData[i].expand = true;
        myTreeData[i].text = myTreeData[i].text;
        var myTreeDataChildren = myTreeData[i].children;
        if (myTreeDataChildren.length >= 1) {
            for (var j = 0; j < myTreeDataChildren.length; j++) {
                if (myTreeDataChildren[j].textValue == null) {
                    myTreeDataChildren[j].text = myTreeDataChildren[j].Display
                } else {
                    myTreeDataChildren[j].text = myTreeDataChildren[j].textValue
                }

                myTreeDataChildren[j].leaf = true;
            }
        }
    }
    var myTreePanel = Ext.getCmp('myTreePanel');
    var myTreePanelStore = myTreePanel.getStore();
    myTreePanelStore.loadData(myTreeData);
}
```

Here my store is setting perfectly, but on click of the node I am able to open child element but when i am clicking there again it should close/ collapse but that is not happening.

Can anybody suggest me to load the store in better way and also close and collapse should work as expected.